# How to boot from USB install medium despite error: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]:

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, kubuntu, live-usb

I have a new laptop from Gigabyte with an NVIDIA RTX card in it, which looks to be the issue.

**Edit**: The model is called "G5 KE-52DE213SD".

When I boot from a freshly written USB stick with Kubuntu 22.04 in an attempt to install it as a dual boot after just having installed Windows 10 on half of the internal SSD, in the usual Linux start log, it will get stuck at the line `[FAILED] Failed to start Ubuntu live CD installer` and then the given error quoted in the headline.

I only found suggestions like these that revolve around installing drivers on an already existing installation, which seem less helpful for my scenario with a bootable USB stick: [superuser thread about this error](https://superuser.com/questions/1750975/nouveau-00000100-0-drm-failed-to-idle-channel-0-drm).

Is there a way that I can persuade this thing to boot, and install Kubuntu on my laptop?

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure boot on? Are you booting in UEFI mode? Have you updated firmware for UEFI & SSD? Much older Gigabyte had UEFI setting for 3D graphics that caused issues.

Comment: This is a rather new laptop. Last week when first turning it on (it came with no OS), I wanted to boot a USB stick with Memtest86+ on it, it would not let me, so I turned off UEFI secure boot, IIRC it was, and then it worked. It let me also install Windows10 with the setting as it is without complaints. I don't understand at all what UEFI setting has to do with a gfx card driver, could you elaborate?

Comment: If UEFI Secure Boot is on, you as the owner had to authorize the install of the nVidia binary blob for Secure boot with a MOK key. Machine owner key(MOK). Ubuntu cannot authorize it as it is proprietary. That complicates UEFI Secure boot installs, but does not prevent them. Your issue may be other UEFI settings. Windows may also have reset some UEFI settings, so you may need to review them again.

Comment: Thanks. For all I can tell, it's still disabled.

Comment: Not seen many Gigabyte laptops. I have an older Gigabyte motherboard and it just works. When I first built system, I had to use yet to be released version of Ubuntu to get newest kernel & drivers & have it work. Had worked well every since with current LTS versions. What model laptop?

Comment: It's called "G5 KE-52DE213SD". A gaming laptop. Not that I do much of that, but dabble in graphics programming, 3D modelling, and though I'll buy a quicker one this time so it won't be obsolete so quickly (power wise), and Dell, Lenovo etc with similarly fast CPU, amount of RAM and non-shared-gfx, cost plenty more.

Comment: Have seen many that use different port, different flash drive, redo ISO or verify it, or different tool to create installer and then it works. No consistent issue. Did see this on Clevo driver. https://www.reddit.com/r/gigabyte/comments/uv0vui/linux_keyboard_driver_for_g5_laptops/